# Same helper methods for two different classes (design problem) C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class hierarchy as follows:

```
struct Arg {
    Info someSpecificInfo;
    OtherInfo anotherInfo
}

class BaseEvaluator {
    public:
        BaseEvaluator (Info info) {};
        virtual Result evaluate();
}


class SpecificEvaluator1 : public BaseEvaluator {
    public:
        Derived(Info info): Base(info) {};
        Result evaluate();
}


class SpecificEvaluator2: public BaseEvaluator {
    public:
        SpecificEvaluator2(Info info): Base(info) {};
        Result evaluate();
}
```

However, I currently need to implement two specific `Evaluator` classes. One of which uses the Info object (essentially another `SpecificEvaluator3` class). However, the other `Evaluator` requires the entire `Arg` Object.

Now I know that for OOP, I should not be mixing these two classes, and essentially I should change `BaseEvaluator` to `InfoEvaluator` and create another `ArgEvaluator` Class, and maybe both of these can inherit from a base `BaseEvaluator` class that has the `evalute()` method.

However, the problem is that for these two `Evaluator` classes, they largely utilize the same helper methods, where these helper methods utilize the Info member variable. I can visualize my two`Evaluator` classes as follows:

```
class ArgSpecificEvaluator {
    public:
        ArgSpecificEvaluator (Arg arg) {};
        Result evaluate(); // Implementation Uses OtherInfo
    protected:
        void helperMethod1(Info);
        void helperMethod2(Info);
}

class SpecificEvaluator3 : BaseEvaluator {
    public:
        SpecificEvaluator3(Info info): {};
        Result evaluate();
    protected:
        void helperMethod1(Info);
        void helperMethod2(Info);
}
```

As you can see there is repeated code for the helperMethods1. Since for `ArgSpecificEvaluator`, the helper method is the same when we use `arg.Info` instead of just `info` as arguments directly. In such case, how to do reconcile this?

Do I switch to just using `Arg` for all the classes? The reason I do not do so, is because there is no need to the `SpecificEvaluator` classes to even touch `OtherInfo`. `SpecificEvaluator3` is kind of a special case where it definitely is a type of evaluator, but has characteristics of the `ArgSpecificEvaluator` as they both utilize the same helper methods. Initially, the helperMethods() are supposed to have no arguments and utilize the member variable `Info` but this scenario is much harder to reconcile so I decided to abstract and put it in the arguments instead.

In a way, what I want to achieve is the Java equivalent of `SpecificEvaluator3` inheriting from base class, but implementing an interface with the helper methods. How do I approach this in C++? Multiple Inheritance?

Comment: You already have Info from base member. Why not just store OtherInfo separately by classes which need it?

Comment: Java interfaces are a special case of multiple inheritance. If you feel like you would use interfaces in Java, then you probably want to implement the same design with multiple inheritance in C++.

Comment: Do `helperMethod{1,2}` need to be members?  Can they be free functions?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Actually this situation is a simplication. It's more like `Arg` struct has many other fields and `Info` field, and our Evaluator only need the `Info` field, while our `ArgEvaluator` needs all of the other fields including `Info`. The issue is the repeated code with `ArgEvaluator` and `SpecificEvaluator` because they essentially utilize the same helper methods

Comment: @StephenNewell Techincally they can be because I can do something like `helperMethod(Info info)` and then let `ArgEvaluator` and `SpecificEvaluator` call this on its own, but I'm wondering if there is a way where the helper methods are class methods and how we can use inheritance to overcome this?

Comment: I'd just make them free functions if they don't need to be members.  Not every pattern fits nicely in OO, and in my experience helper functions in particular work better free.  If I was in Java, these would be `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you are trying to achieve is either something like this:

```
class ArgSpecificEvaluator : public SpecificEvaluator3 {
public:
   ArgSpecificEvaluator (Arg arg) : Base(arg.info) {};
   Result evaluate() override; // Implementation Uses OtherInfo
}
    
class SpecificEvaluator3 : BaseEvaluator {
public:
   SpecificEvaluator3(Info info): {};
   virtual Result evaluate();
protected:
   void helperMethod1(Info);
   void helperMethod2(Info);
}
```

Or that

```
class Helper {
protected:
   Helper(Whatever youneed);
   void helperMethod1(Info);
   void helperMethod2(Info);
}

class ArgSpecificEvaluator : public BaseEvaluator, protected Helper {
public:
   ArgSpecificEvaluator (Arg arg) {};
   Result evaluate() override; // Implementation Uses OtherInfo

}
    
class SpecificEvaluator3 : public BaseEvaluator , protected Helper {
public:
   SpecificEvaluator3(Info info): {};
   Result evaluate() override;
}
```

Note that i set `ArgSpecificEvaluator` to also inherite the base `BaseEvaluator`  because it has the same `evaluate` function.

In general, i try to go around the caveheat of inheritance by rather having an instance of a common class as a member rather than inheriting a class.

```
class Helper {
public:
   Helper(Whatever youneed);
   void helperMethod1(Info);
   void helperMethod2(Info);
}

class ArgSpecificEvaluator : public BaseEvaluator {
public:
   ArgSpecificEvaluator (Arg arg) {};
   Result evaluate() override; // Implementation Uses OtherInfo
protected:
   Helper helper;

}
    
class SpecificEvaluator3 : public BaseEvaluator {
public:
   SpecificEvaluator3(Info info): {};
   Result evaluate() override;
protected:
   Helper helper;
}
```

I would imagine that using `Arg` for all classes and having no-value or a default value in some cases is probably not a bad solution either.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution! May I ask for your solution 1, would it be bad practice to have `arg.info` as a member variable (due to the base class), and then having the entire Arg (which also contains arg.info) as another member since our `evaluate()` utilizes the entire Arg object? Because that is kind of my current scenario

Comment: I would say if u have any duplicate, u r doing something wrong. Probably ur best bet is to have Arg as member in ur base class. Simply filling in half of it when the constructor only takes info as arguments. I can hardly comment more without really seeing the actual code.